# Is $E[Y (X_1+X_2)^2| \mathbf{X}] = (e^{3X_1}+3X_2) E[Y | \mathbf{X}]$ for $\mathbf{X} = [X_1 X_2]^T$?

Tags: probability, random-variable, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Let $\mathbf{X} = [X_1 X_2]^T$ be a vector of random variables and let $Y$ be another random variable that is dependent in some way on $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Suppose we want to calculate $E[Y (e^{3X_1}+3X_2)| \mathbf{X}]$.

Can we simply say
$$
E[Y (e^{3X_1}+3X_2)| \mathbf{X}] = (e^{3X_1}+3X_2) E[Y | \mathbf{X}],
$$
or, alternatively, can we say
$$
E[Y (e^{3X_1}+3X_2)| X_1,X_2] = (e^{3X_1}+3X_2) E[Y | X_1,X_2].
$$

Basically I'm trying to take the property $E[g(X)Y|X] = g(X)E[Y|X]$ which features conditioning on a single random variable, and use it for the case of conditioning on multiple random variables. But I'm not sure if this allowed. I'm also not sure of the notation, that's why I gave two suggestions above.

Are either/both of the above identities correct/incorrect?

Comment: This is called [taking out what is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2939546/explain-conditional-expectations-and-taking-out-measurable-random-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both notations are correct and you can do them. Once you conditioned on a random variable or vector, you can treat any function of it that doesn't include other RVs as a constant and take it out from the expectation.